# Bash-Script: How to insert Variables into Bash-Script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, variable, openconnect

The following bash script is working completely fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo '!PaSsWoRd!' | openconnect --csd-wrapper=/home/user/.cisco/csd-wrapper.sh --authenticate --user=abcde123 --authgroup="tunnel My Company" --passwd-on-stdin vpn.mycompany.com
```

---

However, I want to replace the previous input parameters with variables like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

WRAPPER=/home/user/.cisco/csd-wrapper.sh
USER=abcde123
PASSWD=!PaSsWoRd!
AUTHGROUP=tunnel My Company
DOMAIN=vpn.mycompany.com

echo '$PASSWD' | openconnect --csd-wrapper=$WRAPPER --authenticate --user=$USER --authgroup="$AUTHGROUP" --passwd-on-stdin $DOMAIN
```

Unfortunately this attempt does not work anymore. I think I have to put in some quote chars or similar. Do you know what is wrong with the bash script below?

Comment: See what [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) thinks about your script. But also note that `AUTHGROUP=tunnel My Company` is the syntactically correct way to run the command `My` with the argument `Company` while first setting the environment variable `AUTHGROUP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of quotes around the assignment to a variable containing `!` is the problem here. The shell tries to interpret the `!` character to run the history expansion first before assigning it to the variable. The quoting should prevent the shell from interpreting the contents within as `'..'` as special and keep it as-is.

The assignment should have been written as

```
PASSWD='!PaSsWoRd!'
```

and pass the variable with quoted expansion

```
echo "$PASSWD" | openconnect --csd-wrapper="$WRAPPER" --authenticate --user="$USER" --authgroup="$AUTHGROUP" --passwd-on-stdin "$DOMAIN"
```

Or turn of the history expansion in the script temporarily by including the line, `set +H` at the top of the script. Subsequently do `set -H` at the end to disable it. This is not recommended and much recommended to use the proper quoted approach above.

Comment: There's no issue with the assignment to `PASSWD`. There _is_ an issue with the assignment to `AUTHGROUP`.

Comment: @Kusalananda : I’m pretty sure assignment of a string containing ! to a variable without proper quotes wouldn’t work

Comment: There is no issue with this in a non-interactive script since history expansion wouldn't be triggered.  There are _other_ good reasons for quoting the password though, as it may contain characters from `$IFS`, which would make for _different_ problems (the same as in the assignment to `AUTHGROUP`).

Answer (score 1):

The same (correct) logic that you are applying when using strings in your first example has to be used when *assigning* strings to variables, too.

In `AUTHGROUP=tunnel My Company` the three words are split. And `PASSWD=!PaSsWoRd!` works in a script, but bear in mind that the `!` would be interpreted in a shell, triggering history expansion.

Note that single quotes will preserve the literal value of each enclosed character, while double quotes will allow for exceptions: `$`, `` ` ``, `\` and `!` (see QUOTING in `man bash`). Then, `PASSWD='!PaSsWoRd!'` will work, `PASSWD="!PaSsWoRd!"` won't (but, again, `!` is problematic only in interactive shells, not in scripts).

At the same time, you will need double quotes when *using* variables: `echo '$PASSWD'` will echo the literal `$PASSWD`, not the variable's value.